# How to filter out a column entry in YUI Datatable that ends with a given string

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

Currently, I am working on a YUI datatable with hundreds of entries. The table consists of four columns, the first one (ID) being the primary key. What we want to do is to ignore any entries whose ID "ends with" a specific number. The source code is very big and ugly, so instead of posting code snippets, I wanted to post a rather high level question.

I've seen several YUI datatable samples, but none of them examplified what I want to do, namely filtering out data that ends with a given string. Has any of you been able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting to filter the data before it is bound to the datatable?  Have you looked at the datasource events such as [doBeforeCallback](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.DataSourceBase.html#method_doBeforeCallback)?